# JavaFX ListView high cpu usage

Tags: java, listview, javafx

hey guys i want to ask about the high cpu usage in javafx is it normal or not?

[image]

[image]
the layout composes of a vbox that hold the day layout (sunday, monday....) the day layout has a listview of type room (each room has a layout that contains a label and a listview of type event)
a room has multiple events from 7 am to 10 pm (events could be empty)

this is the layout that i used it's complex i know but is there a simple solution that would make it faster?
by the way i am trying to build a school schedule manager and this is my attempt if anyone has an efficent and better way to do this please say

to explain it better :

this is a representation of a school weekly schedule
the school has multiple rooms each room with a 15 h schedule
the schedule is full of events (empty or full with lectures)

the high cpu usage is likely due to the amount of data that's being loaded from the listviews because each room list view renders 15 h of event layouts this repeats for the number of room and all of this also repeats for each day of the weak

snippets of code :

```
 public void get_week_days(){


  Platform.runLater(() -> {

      Task<Boolean> load_calendar=new Task<Boolean>() {
          @Override
          protected Boolean call() throws Exception {



              

                  try{


                      FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Calendar/cells_designs/day_layout.fxml"));
                      HBox layout=loader.load();
                      DayLayout_controller dayLayoutController=loader.getController();
                      dayLayoutController.set_day(new Calendar_day(week_day_name,i,month,null));
                      dayLayoutController=null;


                      try {
                          Thread.sleep(3000);
                      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                          throw new RuntimeException(e);
                      }
                      Platform.runLater(() -> {
                          day_list.getChildren().add(layout);
                      });



                  }catch (Exception e){
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }



              }


              return null;
          }
      };





      new Thread(load_calendar).start();
  });



}
```

this method is used to populate the vbox with days of the week layout
[image]

this layout contains a listview that's used for the rooms

[image]

each room layout has an  event list-view with 15h worth of events
each empty layout represents half and hour for example 8:00 to 8:30
this hoever doesn't apply to a full event (levture) which could take more which reduces the number of events (8:00 to 10:00 )
to explain it simply (a room that has only empty events has a total of 26 empty events while a room that has a full 2 h lecture has 22

the code for the list-cells :
the room list-cell :

```
public class Calendar_rooms_cell extends ListCell<Rooms> {
private HBox layout;
private Room_layout_controller roomLayoutController;

private String room_day;
private int month_day;
private int month;

public Calendar_rooms_cell(Calendar_day room_day){

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Calendar/cells_designs/Room_layout.fxml"));

    try {
        layout = loader.load();
        roomLayoutController = loader.getController();
        this.room_day = room_day.getDay();
        this.month_day = room_day.getMonth_day();
        this.month = room_day.getMonth();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


@Override
protected void updateItem(Rooms room, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(room, empty);
    if(room==null || empty){
        setGraphic(null);
        setText(null);
    }
    else{

    roomLayoutController.set_room_name(room.getRoom_name(),room_day,month_day,month);

    setGraphic(layout);
    setText(null);
    }
}
```

}

the code for the event-cell :

```
public class Event_cell  extends ListCell<Event>  {
private StackPane layout;
private FXMLLoader loader;

private Label time;


private Calendar_event_layout_controller calendarEventLayoutController;

private Calendar_menu_controller menu;



private Calendar_shared calendarSharedData;






public Event_cell() {

    try{
        loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Calendar/cells_designs/Calendar_event_layout.fxml"));
        layout=loader.load();
        calendarEventLayoutController=loader.getController();

        calendarSharedData=Calendar_shared.get_data();
        menu=calendarSharedData.getCalendarMenuController();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void updateItem(Event event, boolean b) {
    super.updateItem(event, b);
    if(event==null || b){
        setGraphic(null);
        setText(null);
    }

    else{






    if(event.getClass()== Private_lessons.class){
        calendarEventLayoutController.set_up_private_lessons((Private_lessons)event);
    }
    else if(event.getClass()== Formation_event.class){
        calendarEventLayoutController.set_up_formation_events((Formation_event) event);
    }
    else{
        calendarEventLayoutController.set_up_empty_events(event);
    }

    setGraphic(layout);
    setText(null);
    }
}


}
```

the set_room method that creates empty events and filters the observable list for the full events :

```
public void set_room_name(String room_name,String room_day,int month_day,int month){

    ObservableList<Event> filtered_events= FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    room_events.setItems(filtered_events);

    room_events.getItems().clear();

    this.room_name.setText(room_name);



        for(LocalTime time=LocalTime.of(7,00) ; time.compareTo(LocalTime.of(20,00))!=0 ;time=time.plusMinutes(30)){

            LocalTime finalTime = time;
            Optional<Event> events_exists = null;
            FilteredList<Event> events = null;

                if(all_events!=null){

                    if(!all_events.isEmpty()){
                         events= new FilteredList<>(all_events,event -> event.getRoom().equals(room_name)
                                && event.getEvent_day().equals(room_day) &&
                                event.getEvent_start().compareTo(finalTime)==0);

                        events_exists=events.stream().findAny();
                    }

                }



           if(events_exists!=null){

               if(events_exists.isPresent()){



                   for(Event event: events.stream().toList()){

                       if(event.getClass()== Private_lessons.class){

                           Private_lessons privateLessons=(Private_lessons)event;
                           if(privateLessons.getEvent_date()==null){
                               filtered_events.add(privateLessons);
                           }
                           else{
                               if(month_day==privateLessons.getEvent_date().getDayOfMonth() && month==privateLessons.getEvent_date().getMonthValue()){
                                   filtered_events.add(privateLessons);
                               }
                           }


                       }

                       else if(event.getClass()== Formation_event.class){
                           filtered_events.add(event);
                       }


                       time=event.getEvent_end().minusMinutes(30);

                   }

               }

               else{
                   Event event=new Event(time,time.plusMinutes(30),room_day,room_name);
                   filtered_events.add(event);
               }


           }




        }

        room_events.setCellFactory(eventListView -> {
            return new Event_cell();
        });


    }
```

//

there are 7 parent nodes (day of week nodes ) each day of week node contains a list view this list view is filled with room nodes (multiple rooms ) each room node contains a list-view this one is filled with events (time slots)
[image]

i tried lazy loading it worked for the most part but it's so slow

Comment: It's difficult to tell if the CPU usage is expected or if there is a better implementation without a [mre].

Comment: Unrelated, but there is no need to wrap the call to create a task and start it in a runLater call, the [javadoc for Task](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) mentions this: "initially configuring a Task, which may safely be done from any thread".  Also, it is best to follow [naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).  And performance of `ListView` with customized cells regressed in some JavaFX versions, so ensure you are using the latest stable version (currently, 21.0.2)

Comment: We need more than that code you added to be of some help. A [mre] would be best. How many children are in this `VBox`? What does your `ListCell` implementation look like? How many nodes are being displayed at once? How are you creating these nodes?

Comment: @Slaw the vbox contains 7 children (7 days of the current week ) , for the list cells i have 2 list cells a room list-cell and an event list cell i'll edit the question and post the code for the list-cell

Comment: As others have said, there's some key stuff missing...however...then numbers here which are hundreds or maybe a few thousand Nodes shouldn't melt your CPU unless you're doing something horribly wrong.  What's missing is the FXML for your room layout and event layout cells.  But I'm guessing that you have nested ListViews here.  Your room/day Cell contains a horizontal ListView to hold the events.  I'm going to further guess that updateItem() in the room/day Cell triggers a rebuild of the ListView held inside it.  That rebuild is causing your problem.

Comment: You need to architect it such that the ListViews contained inside the day/room Cells are initialized in the constructor of the day/room cells.  If I was doing it, the Model for the room/day list would have name, room day, month day, month, List<Events>.  The updateItem() for the room/day Cell would just replace the backing list for the enclosed events ListView with the new one.  Instead, you're passing a few parameters to an FXMLController, and there's no list of events in those parameters.  So that FXML Controller has to be fetching them somehow.  Hopefully not from a DB call!

Comment: @DaveB well you're almost correct in the room cell mainly in the update item method i call the set_room method  on the controller of the layout this (set_room) method creates the empty events in a loop but not just that i have an observable list with all the full events i go through the loop (the loop iterates through a local time variable) then it filters the observable list for full events if it matches the time , room_name and day of the event , if it find an event it then jumps the loop to the end time of the filtered event and so on till it reaches the end which is 10 pm

Comment: i'll share the set_room method check the edited question please and thank you for listening  @DaveB

Comment: @DaveB should i change my ui to use a table view / tree table view approach ? or shouldi optimize my approach instead to use less cpu

Comment: @Fever_Dream I wouldn't do that.  It's really a data organization thing,IMHO.  For each room/day I'd have a model that had the informational stuff (like name) and then a list of EventModels.  EventModel would have the day, time, type and stuff like that.  Whatever your data loading process is, it would full populate a list for each room/day.  The cell for each room/day would have a ListView and a room/date Label box.  From your screenshot, when the program runs, it'll create about 8 room/date cells, each of which will contain a ListView that has about 12 event cells created.

Comment: When the updateItem() on a room/date cell is called (whenever a new room/date cycles into the viewport), it will replace the contents of the List backing the Event ListView with those from that room/date model.  And then the updateItem() will be called for all of those Event cells that are in the ViewPort for that ListView.  No new layouts should be created, and no new ListViews should be created.  It should not melt your CPU.

Comment: If you wish, you can use a profiler such as [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/download.html) to profile your application and determine exactly where it is spending its time.  Profiling correctly takes some time and skill, especially to avoid [red herrings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) that may be found, which may be quite a few when undertaking such a task.

Comment: I actually think this is a case of how you want to display your data. Right now, you have a `ListView` within a `ListView` within a `ListView`. To me, this seems like a terrible way to display your data. I would consider `Pagination`, `GridView`, `TableView`, and `ListView` in some combination.

Comment: I don't see why an end user would want all of this data displayed at one time. Display data as needed. Thinking in this manner. I would first have the users click on a day. That would then take them to a list of rooms they could click on. That would then take them to a list of time.